# Open points from separate paths won't join

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

I'm trying to join these separate paths so that the black outline is seamless. For some reason the open endpoints between two points won't join with the Join command. I have tried the Divide tool on Pathfinder, as well as the Paint Bucket Tool, but cannot get the effect I am wanting.

[image]

[image]]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This warning indicates either one path is *inside a group* and the other path is not in a group.

Or *both* paths are in *different* and *separate* groups.

Or at least one path is a text path or graph path.

In order to join anchors of *separate* paths, **both** paths need to...

- **not** be in *any* groups
- both paths must be in *the **same** group* if grouped
- **not** be a text path
- **not** be a path within a graph (chart)

Answer (score 0):

Isolate the strokes on a separate layer from the grey fills, turn on smart guides so you get snapping, and make ***dead*** sure that the knots / nodes are *actually* directly aligned / coincident - try joining again.

When / if the join fails, note what the fail dialogue gives as the reason: it *may* be as simple as these two items being in separate groups, which is easy to fix.

Comment: I added a picture of the notification I get, as well as a picture of two endpoints selected. I don't know what directly aligned/ coincident means, could you clarify? Smart guides is turned on. I tried isolating the paths onto a new layer but it did not change anything.

Comment: @Ryan - join works if you align two knots DIRECTLY over one another - so you snap one point onto the other, select BOTH knots with the direct select tool (white arrow) *then* invoke Join. It does **not** create path element between two unconnected points.

Comment: This isn't working either. Is there anything else you know of that I could try?

Comment: Sure looks like you have them each in separate groups from the dialogue - ungroup everything and try again mate!

Comment: I had them in a compound path. Once I released this it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @GerardFalla points don't actually need to be aligned to be joined and it will create a path between them

Comment: @Cai - thanks - yup I've since played around enough to know that in CC that's true... and here I'm showing my... <ahem> experience... as I recall, back in Illustrator 8 through 10, Join didn't create new vector paths and the anchors had to be touching.